# How come up with $a^2+b^2+ab=(a+b+\sqrt{ab})(a+b-\sqrt{ab})$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I know the identity
$$
a^2+b^2+ab=(a+b+\sqrt{ab})(a+b-\sqrt{ab})
$$
However, suppose I'm given $a^2+b^2+ab$ but don't the identity. How should I come up with the identity? Any tricks?

Should I maybe start from $(a+b)(a-b)=a^2-b^2$?

Comment: It’s $(a+b)^2-\sqrt{ab}^2$

Answer (score 7):

Notice that it is a difference of two squares $$ a^2 +ab +b^2 = a^2 +2ab +b^2 -ab = (a+b)^2 -(\sqrt{ab} )^2 $$

Comment: In High School math competitions in New York in the nineteen fifties this was known as "disguised difference of squares".

Answer (score 1):

Substitute $a+b$ with $c$. Now, we have

$(c + \sqrt{ab})(c - \sqrt{ab})$.

That is the same as $c^2 - (\sqrt{ab})^2$.

Since $c = (a + b)$, we now have $(a + b)^2 - (\sqrt{ab})^2$.

We know that $(a + b)^2 = (a + b)(a + b) = a^2 + b^2 + 2ab$ and $(\sqrt{ab})^2 = ab$, hence $(a + b)^2 - (\sqrt{ab})^2 = a^2 + b^2 + 2ab - ab$.

And thus, we conclude that $(a^2 + b^2 + ab) = (a+b + \sqrt{ab})(a+b - \sqrt{ab})$.